# Number formatting in template strings (Javascript - ES6)

Tags: javascript, string-formatting, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I was wondering if it is possible to format numbers in Javascript template strings, for example something like:

```
var n = 5.1234;
console.log(`This is a number: $.2d{n}`);
// -> 5.12
```

Or possibly

```
var n = 5.1234;
console.log(`This is a number: ${n.toString('.2d')}`);
// -> 5.12
```

That syntax obviously doesn't work, it is just an illustration of the type of thing I'm looking for.

I am aware of tools like `sprintf` from `underscore.string`, but this seems like something that JS should be able to do out the box, especially given the power of template strings.

**EDIT**

As stated above, I am already aware of 3rd party tools (e.g. sprintf) and customised functions to do this.  Similar questions (e.g. [JavaScript equivalent to printf/String.Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)) don't mention template strings at all, probably because they were asked before the ES6 template strings were around.  My question is specific to ES6, and is independent of implementation.  I am quite happy to accept an answer of "No, this is not possible" if that is case, but what would be great is either info about a new ES6 feature that provides this, or some insight into whether such a feature is on its way.

Comment: It's possible in Adobe JavaScript. `util.printf` Otherwise we have to wait until ECMAScript 6 is available...

Comment: @WhiteHat - check your calendar

Comment: Yeah but where can I use it? IE 9 is standard issue where I work, just complaining a little there.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, ES6 does not introduce any new number formatting functions, you will have to live with the existing [`.toExponential(fractionDigits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toExponential), [`.toFixed(fractionDigits)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), [`.toPrecision(precision)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision), [`.toString([radix])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) and [`toLocaleString(…)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) (which has been updated to optionally support the [ECMA-402 Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm), though).
Template strings have nothing to do with number formatting, they just desugar to a function call (if tagged) or string concatenation (default).

If those `Number` methods are not sufficient for you, you will have to roll your own. You can of course write your formatting function as a template string tag if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to use the toFixed() method of a number:

```
var num = 5.1234;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use ES6 tag functions here's how such a tag function would look,

```
function d2(pieces) {
    var result = pieces[0];
    var substitutions = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

    for (var i = 0; i < substitutions.length; ++i) {
        var n = substitutions[i];

        if (Number(n) == n) {
            result += Number(substitutions[i]).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            result += substitutions[i];
        }

        result += pieces[i + 1];
    }

    return result;
}
```

which can then be applied to a template string thusly,

```
d2`${some_float} (you can interpolate as many floats as you want) of ${some_string}`;
```

that will format the float and leave the string alone.

Comment: Nice! This should be the accepted answer. Here's a fully ES6 version with "rest" args: https://codepen.io/garyo/pen/gZYmNP

Answer (score 2):

While template-string interpolation formatting is not available as a built-in, you can get equivalent behavior with [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat):

```
const format = (num, fraction = 2) => new Intl.NumberFormat([], {
  minimumFractionDigits: fraction,
  maximumFractionDigits: fraction,
}).format(num);

format(5.1234); // -> '5.12'
```

Note that regardless of your implementation of choice, you might get bitten by rounding errors:

```
(9.999).toFixed(2) // -> '10.00'

new Intl.NumberFormat([], {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2, // <- implicit rounding!
}).format(9.999) // -> '10.00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fully ES6 version of Filip Allberg's solution above, using ES6 "rest" params. The only thing missing is being able to vary the precision; that could be done by making a factory function. Left as an exercise for the reader.

```js
function d2(strs, ...args) {
    var result = strs[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
        var n = args[i];
        if (Number(n) == n) {
            result += Number(args[i]).toFixed(2);
        } else {
            result += args[i];
        }
        result += strs[i+1];
    }
    return result;
}

f=1.2345678;
s="a string";
console.log(d2`template: ${f} ${f*100} and ${s} (literal:${9.0001})`);
```

Answer (score 1):

based on [ES6 Tagged Templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51680250/711085), this will emulate typical template string syntax in other languages (this is loosely based on python f-strings; I avoid calling it `f` in case of name overlaps):

Demo:

```
> F`${(Math.sqrt(2))**2}{.0f}`  // normally 2.0000000000000004
"2"

> F`${1/3}{%} ~ ${1/3}{.2%} ~ ${1/3}{d} ~ ${1/3}{.2f} ~ ${1/3}"
"33% ~ 33.33% ~ 0 ~ 0.33 ~ 0.3333333333333333"

> F`${[1/3,1/3]}{.2f} ~ ${{a:1/3, b:1/3}}{.2f} ~ ${"someStr"}`
"[0.33,0.33] ~ {\"a\":\"0.33\",\"b\":\"0.33\"} ~ someStr
```

Fairly simple code using :

```
var FORMATTER = function(obj,fmt) {
    /* implements things using (Number).toFixed:
       ${1/3}{.2f} -> 0.33
       ${1/3}{.0f} -> 1
       ${1/3}{%} -> 33%
       ${1/3}{.3%} -> 33.333%
       ${1/3}{d} -> 0
       ${{a:1/3,b:1/3}}{.2f} -> {"a":0.33, "b":0.33}
       ${{a:1/3,b:1/3}}{*:'.2f',b:'%'} -> {"a":0.33, "b":'33%'}  //TODO not implemented
       ${[1/3,1/3]}{.2f} -> [0.33, 0.33]
       ${someObj} -> if the object/class defines a method [Symbol.FTemplate](){...}, 
                     it will be evaluated; alternatively if a method [Symbol.FTemplateKey](key){...} 
                     that can be evaluated to a fmt string; alternatively in the future 
                     once decorators exist, metadata may be appended to object properties to derive 
                     formats //TODO not implemented
    */
    try {
        let fracDigits=0,percent;
        if (fmt===undefined) {
            if (typeof obj === 'string')
                return obj;
            else
                return JSON.stringify(obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof Array)
            return '['+obj.map(x=> FORMATTER(x,fmt))+']'
        else if (typeof obj==='object' && obj!==null /*&&!Array.isArray(obj)*/)
            return JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k,v])=> [k,FORMATTER(v,fmt)])));
        else if (matches = fmt.match(/^\.(\d+)f$/))
            [_,fracDigits] = matches;
        else if (matches = fmt.match(/^(?:\.(\d+))?(%)$/))
            [_,fracDigits,percent] = matches;
        else if (matches = fmt.match(/^d$/))
            fracDigits = 0;
        else
            throw 'format not recognized';
        
        if (obj===null)
            return 'null';
        if (obj===undefined) {
            // one might extend the above syntax to 
            // allow for example for .3f? -> "undefined"|"0.123"
            return 'undefined';
        }
        
        if (percent)
            obj *= 100;
        
        fracDigits = parseFloat(fracDigits);
        return obj.toFixed(fracDigits) + (percent? '%':'');
    } catch(err) {
        throw `error executing F\`$\{${someObj}\}{${fmt}}\` specification: ${err}`
    }
}

function F(strs, ...args) {
    /* usage: F`Demo: 1+1.5 = ${1+1.5}{.2f}` 
          --> "Demo: 1+1.5 = 2.50" 
    */
    let R = strs[0];
    args.forEach((arg,i)=> {
        let [_,fmt,str] = strs[i+1].match(/(?:\{(.*)(?<!\\)\})?(.*)/);
        R += FORMATTER(arg,fmt) + str;
    });
    return R;
}
```

sidenote: The core of the code is as follows. The heavy lifting is done by the formatter. The negative lookbehind is somewhat optional, and to let one escape actual curly braces.

```
    let R = strs[0];
    args.forEach((arg,i)=> {
        let [_,fmt,str] = strs[i+1].match(/(?:\{(.*)(?<!\\)\})?(.*)/);
        R += FORMATTER(arg,fmt) + str;
    });
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use es6 tag functions. I don't know ready for use of that.

It might look like this:

```
num`This is a number: $.2d{n}`
```

Learn more:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings

Comment: This gives me a syntax error for first, num is not defined and also doesn't work if I remove "num" from the start of it. Any details here?

Comment: A fully working example would have been nice. The MDN link does explain it quite well however.